# A test for SocketServer backlogs in Java

Tags: java, networking

In C I could select/poll a bound sockets file descriptor to check for waiting connections. Now that I am learning java sockets, all I have found is for an equivalent is thread loop ed that constantly tries to accept and waits for the accept to time out or a client to connect.

Is there a way to test the SocketServer class for pending connections in the backlog besides trying and timing out on the accept command? I am looking for way to make a single thread server without having to wait on an accept call to timeout constantly.

Comment: Take a look at the Java NIO packages.

Comment: Thx, that lead me to a post that answers my question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079172/java-server-multiple-ports