# How to poll multiple sockets on java client side?

Tags: java, sockets

I've got a question with my program about Java socket communication. On client side, I need to listen to port 1900 and get the UDP message sent out by another software. Then I need to send the UDP message to Server side through port 1901 and listen to server's response.

At the same time,I still need to listen to local port 1900.That is as 
soon as something occurs on port 1900 and 1901, I need to deal with it. In a word,on client side,I need to monitor port 1900 as well as 1901,and once one of them gets something asynchronously,I need to come to fix it. I think it requires knowledge of Java NIO, but I don't know it exactly. Thank you for advice.

Comment: Show some code. You can easily transfer data from socket 1 to socket 2 if that is what you want.

Comment: well,I konw little about java socket program and I have no code.Thank you for help,I'm going to learn more about it before programing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

`ServerSocketChannel` to do that I think, though I have not yet tried to do the same. You can see this stackoverflow thread for more information.

[Java Server - Multiple ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079172/java-server-multiple-ports)

Comment: Thank you for help,I'm going to learn about SocketChannel.When I get the way,I'm going to share it with you.