# Iterative UDP multi-service server java

Tags: java, udp, serversocket

I need to create a multi-service iterative UDP server providing two services:
service 1: has a port number 2074 and accepts euro from client and return dollars
service 2: has a port number 2075 and accepts dollars from client and return euros

I know how to create a simple UDP server, and how i need to do any conversions.
My problem is that i don't have any idea of how I can create this server in order to implement 2 services. Do i need to use am if statement or something?

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Please tag your questions with the programming language you are using - that will help to get your questions seen by the right people. From the "serversocket" tag I am guessing it is Java - is that right?

Comment: yes you are right :) thanks a lot i have forgot to do that

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Server - Multiple ports?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079172/java-server-multiple-ports)

Comment: no not exactly. some aid which i have says that i shall use the socket function select() and the function FD_ISSET

Comment: that is for C, not Java